# WebClient doesn't fetch data as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm trying to reactively fetch data from external API using two methods from some `Service` class.

I'm new to reactive and Spring in general, so it could be a very obvious mistake but I just can't find it

These are the two methods:

```java
    public Mono<SomeClass> get(int value) {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri("/" + value)
                .retrieve()
                .onRawStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT::equals, clientResponse -> {
                    return Mono.error(new SomeException1("Some message", clientResponse.rawStatusCode()));
                })
                .onRawStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND::equals, clientResponse -> {
                    return requestGeneration(value)
                        .flatMap(res -> Mono.error(new SomeException1("Some message", clientResponse.rawStatusCode())));
                })
                .bodyToMono(SomeClass.class)
                .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(5, Duration.ofSeconds(8))
                        .filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof SomeException1));
    }

    private Mono<Void> requestGeneration(int value) {
        return webClient.post()
                .uri("/" + value)
                .retrieve()
                .onRawStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST::equals, clientResponse -> {
                    return Mono.error(new SomeException2("Wrong value", clientResponse.rawStatusCode()));
                })
                .bodyToMono(Void.class);
    }
```

Baasically what I'm trying to achieve is:

- first `GET` from `http://api.examplepage.com/{value}`
- if that API returns HTTP404 it means I need to first call `POST` to the same URL, because the data is not yet generated
- the second function does the `POST` call and returns `Mono<Void>` because it is just HTTP200 or HTTP400 on bad generation seed (i don't need to process the response)
- first function (`GET` call) could also return HTTP429 which means the data is generating right now, so I need to call again after some time period (5-300 seconds) and check if data has been generated already
- then after some time it results in HTTP200 with generated data which I want to map to `SomeClass` and then return mapped data in controller below

```java
    @PostMapping("/follow/{value}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> someFunction(@PathVariable int value)  {
            return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok(service.get(value)));
    }
```

all the code I posted is very simplified to the issues I'm struggling with and doesn't contain some things I think are not important in this question

and now the actual question:
it doesn't actually make the call? i really don't know what is happening
program doesn't enter `onRawStatus`, even if i change it to `onStatus` 2xx or whatever other httpstatus and log inside i see nothing as if it doesn't even enter the chains

when i manually call with postman it seems like the program calls have never been made because the `GET` call returns 404 (the program didn't request to generate data)

the controller only returns `"scanAvailable": true`, when i expect it to return mapped `SomeClass` json

// edit

i changed the code to be a full chain as suggested and it didn't solve the problem. all the status are still unreachable (code inside any `onStatus` nor `onRawStatus` never executes)

Comment: you are breaking the chain when calling `requestGeneration(value);` by not handling the return. do something like `return requestGeneration(value).someOtherOperator....`

Comment: and when you are getting `"scanAvailable": true` you are most likely serializing a nested `Mono` the function `get` returns a `Mono`then you slap it into a new Mono by using `Mono.just` thats my guess